# Symfony3 console errors

Tags: symfony, console

I use console command: **php bin/console doctrine:database:create**
Symfony deploy in VPS server, Ubuntu 14.04

**And return error:**

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:create  
PHP Warning:  Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException' with message 'Warning: require_once(/var/www/www-root/data/www/likezakaz.ru/../../../apache/htdocs/delivery/app/AppKernel.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory' in /var/www/www-root/data/www/likezakaz.ru/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/DebugClassLoader.php:142
    Stack trace:
    #0 /var/www/www-root/data/www/likezakaz.ru/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/DebugClassLoader.php(142): Symfony\Component\Debug\DebugClassLoader->loadClass()
    #1 [internal function]: Symfony\Component\Debug\DebugClassLoader->loadClass('AppKernel')
    #2 /var/www/www-root/data/www/likezakaz.ru/bin/console(26): spl_autoload_call('AppKernel')
    #3 {main}
      thrown in /var/www/www-root/data/www/likezakaz.ru/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/DebugClassLoader.php on line 142
    PHP Fatal error:  Symfony\Component\Debug\DebugClassLoader::loadClass(): Failed opening required '/var/www/www-root/data/www/likezakaz.ru/../../../apache/htdocs/delivery/app/AppKernel.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/www-root/data/www/likezakaz.ru/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/DebugClassLoader.php on line 142
```

**Attention**, apache/htdocs/delivery it is the path in my localhost server

Answer (score 0):

```
composer install --no-dev --optimaze-autoloader
```

Comment: Can you explain your code and why it solves the issue? *Code only* answers are often not that helpful.